# How to set value based on value existence in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following T-SQL code:

```
select 
    id,
    (case
        when n in(Bla1', 'Bla2') then 1
        when n = 'Bla3' then 99
        else 0
     end) as c
from 
    hello
```

Running this code outputs this result:

```
|  id    | c  |
+--------+----+
| 577140 | 0  |
| 577140 | 1  |
| 577140 | 0  |
| 577140 | 0  |
| 577140 | 99 |
| 577141 | 0  |
| 577141 | 0  |
| 577141 | 0  |
| 577142 | 0  |
| 577142 | 0  |
| 577142 | 1  |
```

How can I modify the code to get the following output?

```
|  id    | c  |
+--------+----+
| 577140 | 99 |
| 577141 | 0  |
| 577142 | 1  |
```

**Rule**

For each `id`: If `99` exists, then `c` becomes `99`. If not, either `1` or `0`, depending if any `1` exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when n in ('Bla1', 'Bla2') then 1
                when n = 'Bla3' then 99
                else 0
           end) as c
from hello
group by id;
```

Comment: I never came up using `max`. I am so stupid... Thanks a bunch!